# ios: Uploading mulitpart file to AmazonS3

Tags: ios, file-upload, amazon-s3, afnetworking, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 from my iOS app. I'm using AFNetworking for network requests. I have the following code for uploading file to S3:

```
func uploadFile(filePath: String, uploadUrl: String, returnDict: NSDictionary? = nil) {
    let fileName = filePath.lastPathComponent
    let fileType = fileName.pathExtension
    if fileName != "" && fileType != "" {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

            manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            manager.requestSerializer.setValue("\(data.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            let request = manager.requestSerializer.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("PUT",
                URLString: uploadUrl,
                parameters: ["Content-Type":"\(fileType)"],
                constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData :AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
                    formData.appendPartWithFileData(data,
                        name: "file",
                        fileName: uploadUrl.lastPathComponent,
                        mimeType: FileUploader.mimeType[fileType])
                },
                error: nil)

            let operation = manager.HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest(request,
                success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
                    println(uploadUrl)
                    self.delegate?.fileUploadComplete?(true, returnDict: returnDict)
                },
                failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    println("Error : " + error.description)
                    self.delegate?.fileUploadComplete?(false, returnDict: nil)
                })

            operation.setUploadProgressBlock({ (bytesWritten: UInt,
                totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) -> Void in
                    println("Wrote \(totalBytesWritten)/\(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
                })

            manager.operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
        }
        else {
            println("File data nil")
            delegate?.fileUploadComplete?(false, returnDict: nil)
        }
    }
    else {
        println("File path not correct")
        delegate?.fileUploadComplete?(false, returnDict: nil)
    }
}
```

The file gets uploaded completely on S3 but is malformed(/corrupted). If I upload an audio the file doesn't play when I redownload it using the same url. The delegate. methods are just for notifying listener for success or failure. As the file size may be too big for my case I need to do multipart upload.